# Changing name of root file breaks the build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am simply trying to change the root folder name from `/app` to `/src`, however, when I do and run `npm start` I get an error:

```
fs.js:582
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/colinsygiel/liquidtool/liquid-tool-system-ui/lts-admin/app/index.html'
```

I went into the `index.html` and changed the corresponding `app` to `src`, yet I continue to get the same error.

I think it has something to do with that it is still trying to look for `index.html` in the `/app`, when it should be looking in `/src`.

If it help, here are my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "analyze:clean": "rimraf stats.json",
    "preanalyze": "npm run analyze:clean",
    "analyze": "node ./internals/scripts/analyze.js",
    "extract-intl": "babel-node --presets latest,stage-0 -- ./internals/scripts/extract-intl.js",
    "npmcheckversion": "node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js",
    "preinstall": "npm run npmcheckversion",
    "postinstall": "npm run build:dll",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:clean",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress",
    "build:clean": "npm run test:clean && rimraf ./build",
    "build:dll": "node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "start:tunnel": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ENABLE_TUNNEL=true node server",
    "start:production": "npm run test && npm run build && npm run start:prod",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "presetup": "npm i chalk shelljs",
    "setup": "node ./internals/scripts/setup.js",
    "postsetup": "npm run build:dll",
    "clean": "shjs ./internals/scripts/clean.js",
    "clean:all": "npm run analyze:clean && npm run test:clean && npm run build:clean",
    "generate": "plop --plopfile internals/generators/index.js",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern internals/scripts",
    "lint:js": "npm run lint:eslint -- . ",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "pretest": "npm run test:clean && npm run lint",
    "test:clean": "rimraf ./coverage",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll",
    "coveralls": "cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls"
  },
```

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const logger = require('./logger');

const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
const setup = require('./middlewares/frontendMiddleware');
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const ngrok = (isDev && process.env.ENABLE_TUNNEL) || argv.tunnel ? require('ngrok') : false;
const resolve = require('path').resolve;
const app = express();

// If you need a backend, e.g. an API, add your custom backend-specific middleware here
// app.use('/api', myApi);

// In production we need to pass these values in instead of relying on webpack
setup(app, {
  outputPath: resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
  publicPath: '/',
});

// get the intended host and port number, use localhost and port 3000 if not provided
const customHost = argv.host || process.env.HOST;
const host = customHost || null; // Let http.Server use its default IPv6/4 host
const prettyHost = customHost || 'localhost';

const port = argv.port || process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Start your app.
app.listen(port, host, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return logger.error(err.message);
  }

  // Connect to ngrok in dev mode
  if (ngrok) {
    ngrok.connect(port, (innerErr, url) => {
      if (innerErr) {
        return logger.error(innerErr);
      }

      logger.appStarted(port, prettyHost, url);
    });
  } else {
    logger.appStarted(port, prettyHost);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you have any other configuration files that include `/app`? Run `grep -rn "/app"` to check (Linux)

Comment: OK, I'm on a Mac, do you know the equivalent command to check?

Comment: Mac can use `grep`

Comment: OK, I get a warning back: "grep: warning: recursive search of stdin"

Comment: What's in your server.js?

Comment: Mac is funny... Try: `grep -rn "/app" .` with the dot. Make sure you run this from your programs root, not your PC's root directory

Comment: OK, I updated question with server.js file. When I ran grep it got one result, but I don't think it has to do with issue because it located "app" in "application"

Comment: I think it has something to do with that it is still trying to look for index.html in the /app, when it should be looking in /src.